# Laravel Migration Postgres error

Tags: php, database, postgresql, laravel-5.3, pgadmin

HI i want to connect Laravel with postgres database.

when i run

```
php artisan migrate
```

it gives me this error.

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]                                                                                                                                                    
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] expected authentication request from server, but received J (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = public and table_name = migrations)  



[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]                                              
SQLSTATE[08006] [7] expected authentication request from server, but received J
```

Comment: Did you find any solution? Fall in the same issue.

Comment: no @Serj.by i moved to mysql let me know if you find the solution

Answer (score 6):

To me the problem was that I forget to change the port from 3306 to 5432

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you have entered correct credentials for the pgsql database.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

check your file on : 
**.env** 
**config/database**

did you type **correct data** for :

DB_CONNECTION=
DB_HOST=
DB_PORT=
DB_DATABASE=
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=

and

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'pgsql'),